# Akeneo images are not loading (ns_error_dom_bad_uri, ns_error_unexpected)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, akeneo

[Akeneo web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opjZX.png)

After logging into Akeneo CE 6.0.108 images are not displayed. What could be the reason?

Below error examples and nginx configuration.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGL7i.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4bHg.png)

[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV7BD.png)
[error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUn0e.png)

nginx sites-available conf

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen   [::]:80;
        server_name 192.168.0.78;

        return 301 https://192.168.0.78$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name 192.168.0.78;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/akeneo.prod-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/akeneo.prod-error.log;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/crt.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crt.pem;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

        location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Secure on;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
        proxy_send_timeout 7200s;
    }
}
```

Before adding certificate and setting redirect in nginx configuration images were displayed.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here on Apache. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add line:
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
on 443